# Converting multiple rows to one row of an internal table in ABAP

Tags: abap, transpose, internal

I have an internal table where (for example) five rows have the same entries with the exception of one column which is language dependant. For my ALV output I want all the language entries in one row next to each other.

In my internal table the column is like:

Polish,
english,
swedish

and in my final output I want it like: polish, english, swedish. If I have only one column I know how to do it I think, but I have a whole internal table with ten columns and I need to assign the right language texts to the right names.

Comment: Please add a MWE including some sample data to make it clear what you are looking for and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have an internal table like this:

material number   language

123    english
123    polish
123    swedish


and I want something like:


material number  language_1 language_2 language_3
123                     english  polish  swedish

Comment: @ImperiousPerfect, did you check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845233/911419) to your question. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I didn't see the notification. My Bad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic language output for structure/internal table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842628/dynamic-language-output-for-structure-internal-table)

Answer (score 0):

That's simple I'd guess:

```
data lv_line type char255.
loop at it_languages into data(ls_languages).
   lv_line  = lv_line && ls_languages-lang.
endloop.
```

append lv_line to lt_lines.

from here you'd only have to display the table on alv.